# How to fix 403 error while scraping with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I keep getting 403 error when using scrapy, even though I have proper headers set. The website, I am trying to scrape is https://steamdb.info/graph/.

My code:

```
def start_request(self):
        headers =  {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Mobile Safari/537.36",
"accept": "application/json",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7",
"cache-control":" no-cache",
"pragma": "no-cache",
"referer": "https://steamdb.info/graph/", 
"sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
"sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
"sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }

        yield scrapy.Request(url = 'https://steamdb.info/graph', method='GET', headers = headers, callback=self.parse)
        

    def parse(self, response):    
        #stuff to do
```

Error:

```
2022-07-08 20:20:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://steamdb.info/graph> (referer: https://steamdb.info/graph/)
2022-07-08 20:20:41 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://steamdb.info/graph>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Comment: do you get 403 error from the start, or it starts to happen consistently after a while, or it just sometimes happens randomly?

Comment: right from the start

Comment: Your URL results in an error for me in the webbrowser. Are you sure, thats the right URL?

Comment: I fixed the url to <steamdb.info/graph>, still get the error

Comment: If I do the request in an incognito window, with dev tools network tab open, I can see the 403 response and a screen that says "security check" before it redirects away to the real screen you wanted to scrape. But it seems like if I go to `https://steamdb.info/graph/` with the trailing slash that doesn't happen - so try that.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work 
```2022-07-09 11:24:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://steamdb.info/graph/> (referer: https://steamdb.info/graph/)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CloudScraper](https://github.com/venomous/cloudscraper) worked for me:

```
pip install cloudscraper
```

Then add middleware to your settings.py:

```
"DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {
    "YOUR_PATH.AntiBanMiddleware": 543
  },
```

Here is the AntiBanMiddleware:

```
class AntiBanMiddleware:
    cloudflare_scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        request_url = request.url
        response_status = response.status
        if response_status not in (403, 503):
            return response

        spider.logger.info("Cloudflare detected. Using cloudscraper on URL: %s", request_url)
        cflare_response = self.cloudflare_scraper.get(request_url)
        cflare_res_transformed = HtmlResponse(url=request_url, body=cflare_response.text, encoding='utf-8')
        return cflare_res_transformed
```

Comment: Simpler, and faster than using my proposed solution via Selenium. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The website is under cloudflare protection.

```
https://steamdb.info/graph/ is using Cloudflare CDN/Proxy!

https://steamdb.info/graph/ is using Cloudflare SSL!
```

It's working with `cloudscraper` which is equivalent to `requests` module can handle cloudflare protection.

```
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = 'https://steamdb.info/graph/'
req = scraper.get(url)
print(req)
```

**Output:**

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: How do I integrate this with scrapy?

Comment: @Baraa Zaidm alternative is scrapy with selenium

Comment: I tried cloudscraper with Beautifulsoup but it's surprisingly very slow. But yes. selenium works 100%. Thank you very much <3

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. If a website is using cloudfare, you can use undetected chrome driver and use it as a `scrapy middleware`.

Add this to Middleware.py:

```
class SeleniumMiddleWare(object):

    def __init__(self):
        path = "G:/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        options.headless=True
        chrome_prefs = {}
        options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
        chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
        chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
        #self.driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        self.driver=  uc.Chrome(options= options, use_subprocess=True, driver_executable_path = path)
       

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        try:
            self.driver.get(request.url)
        except:
            pass
        content = self.driver.page_source
        self.driver.quit()

        return HtmlResponse(request.url, encoding='utf-8', body=content, request=request)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        return response
```

Settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'my_scraper.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleWare': 491 #change my_scraper to your scraper's name
}
```

my_scraper.py:

```
class SeleniumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'steamdb'
    allowed_domains = ['steamdb.info']
    start_urls = ['https://steamdb.info/graph/']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {"title": response.css("h1::text").get()}
```

Comment: from where do you import HtmlResponse?

Comment: @Bruno For me "from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse" worked

Comment: just add that you need `undetected-chromedriver` for work properly: `pip install undetected-chromedriver` and then `import undetected_chromedriver as uc`. `undetected_chromedriver` help to scrape a website with basic anti-bot protection. But I think that for high anti-bot protections is not capable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the site does not exist -https://steamdb.info/graphs/ goes to a 404

thanks

Comment: ah rookie mistake. I fixed the url to <https://steamdb.info/graph/>, still get 403 error